# Send visitor to a CMS page after the Contact Form

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, contact-us, contact-form

In Magento 1.9, after a visitor submits the contact form they get sent back to the contact form page.

How can I send them to a CMS page instead?

(I did try googling this, but the only results I got were for putting the contact form inside a CMS page.)

Answer (score 1):

To implement such feature, you'll have to create a module that overrides the following file: `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`.

The change you need to apply on this file is the following, replace that piece of code under the `postAction` method:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

With the following:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
$this->_redirect('your_cms_page_identifier');
```

Please note that you should only apply this to the `_redirect` that's right after the `addSuccess` line. Do not apply it in the `catch` block nor in the `else` at the end of the function as it would result in people getting redirected to your CMS page even if the request submission fails.

Answer (score 1):

Override the default IndexController of `Mage_Contacts` by adding the below in your config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Module_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">Namespace_Module_Contacts</Namespace_Module_Contacts>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and adding the controller in `Namespace/Module/controllers/Contacts/IndexController.php` and override the `postAction()` function

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';

class Namespace_Module_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController {
    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('cms_page_identifier'); // it redirects to your cms page instead of the default contact form

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.!! Accept the answer, if it worked for you as well..